# How to fix IP address but left port number selected by kernel in DialTCP?

Tags: linux, go, network-programming

From the document, when using net.DailTCP, if laddr == nil, it means we want the kernel to pick an appropriate originating local address.
Since the machine could have multiple network interface, I just want to fix the ip address of laddr but left port number selected by kernel randomly. How Can I do that?

```
func DialTCP(net string, laddr, raddr *TCPAddr) (*TCPConn, error)
```

Comment: I think using port 0 means dynamic port in Linux

Comment: Or in any other TCP implementation ... But why do you want to determine the outgoing IP address? TCP will do that for you via the static routing tables.

Comment: The IP address doesn't determine the interface. That doesn't happen until routing.

Comment: You commented yourself that you should use port 0. Is that not your answer?